# How do I resolve "non-configurable property "ChoiceGroupOption" in a React.js app, I am using Parcel and imported comp from "office-ui-fabric-react"

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, parceljs

I have a React app, I am using Parcel as my bundler. I want to use "office-ui-fabric-react" components. Everything works fine up until I import a Component from "office-ui-fabric-react" (Office Fabric Ui).
This is the error message I get from console -

> TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "ChoiceGroupOption".

I have ensured that all dependencies are installed ("office-UI-fabric-react" does not require any stated dependency).
I then set up a new React project, this time using Create-React-App command to generate the boilerplate. This version doesn't have any issues, even after importing components from "office-ui-fabric-react", it works ok

```
import { PrimaryButton } from "office-ui-fabric-react
```

//just add this line to a Reactjs project using parcel

> TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "ChoiceGroupOption"

Comment: Maybe try to import like this and see if the problem goes away `import { PrimaryButton } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button;"`

Comment: @VitalieBraga thanks, I tried this and it works, although it means that I would have to reference each component separately. Looks like extra work though. This answers my question all the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @VitalieBraga 's recommendation, the solution to this issue is to reference the specific module for every office-UI react component to be imported.
For example

```
import { PrimaryButton } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/button";
import { ChoiceGroup,IChoiceGroupOption} from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/ChoiceGroup";
```

this actually addresses the issue I had, but in regards, the issue of importing multiple components on a single line this is not possible with Parcel.

```
import { css, classNamesFunction, DefaultButton, IStyle, Label, PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
```

The other alternative is to use Webpack as against Parcel